# What is the best way to monitor CPU, disk and memory usage of a single application in Linux?

Tags: linux, display

I do not want to monitor the system's performance with something like vmstat, because it will provide more general information than what I want. I know time provides CPU usage data of the executed process, but I also want process-specific memory usage.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/554/how-to-monitor-cpu-memory-usage-of-a-single-process

Comment: I was jut going to post the `top` solution too, good catch. A web search for the Q title would've found this other Duplicate too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221555/how-can-i-get-the-cpu-usage-and-memory-usage-of-a-single-process-on-linux-ubunt So close I guess...? Or do cross-site Q's that were *not made at the same time by the same person* "count"?

Answer (score 0):

There are good answers on other StackExchange sites already, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221555/how-can-i-get-the-cpu-usage-and-memory-usage-of-a-single-process-on-linux-ubunt) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/554/how-to-monitor-cpu-memory-usage-of-a-single-process), just in case each site like's it's own take on an answer:

```
top -p <pid>
htop -p <pid>
```

These run top / htop monitoring just the supplied pid (or multiple pid's with multiple `-p <pid>` entries.

Or use `ps` (optionally with `--noheader` to skip the first "legend" line:

```
ps -p <pid> -o %cpu,%mem,cmd
```

Though note the comment:  *%cpu "is the CPU time used divided by the time the process has been running (cputime/realtime ratio), expressed as a percentage" (see manpage of ps). This is* not *the real just in time CPU usage. It can also be very different from what top shows, for instance.*